# How to fix slow _TABLE_SUFFIX queries in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

This _TABLE_SUFFIX query took **2.5 secs**:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM `projectid.datasetid.hospital_*`
```

If we add this WHERE statement:

```
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX LIKE '_2_' OR _TABLE_SUFFIX LIKE '_1_'
```

...the query takes **8 minutes and 19 seconds**!

There are only three tables that the first query matches. This is concerning as we are looking at querying and filtering against thousands of tables.

Why are _TABLE_SUFFIX queries so slow and how can they be performed more quickly particularly with REGEX type operations?

Comment: What if you use BETWEEN or IN instead? Do you see the same performance?

Comment: Did it happen one time, or many times? Can't reproduce. Please post job ids for problems like these.

Answer (score 1):

if your underscores in `'_1_'/'_2_'` can only be numbers, all I can propose is to try something like this:

```
select sum(cnt) from (

SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM `projectid.datasetid.hospital_0*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX between '10' and '29'
union all
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `projectid.datasetid.hospital_1*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX between '10' and '29'
union all
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `projectid.datasetid.hospital_2*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX between '10' and '29'
union all
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `projectid.datasetid.hospital_3*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX between '10' and '29'
union all
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `projectid.datasetid.hospital_4*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX between '10' and '29'
union all
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `projectid.datasetid.hospital_5*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX between '10' and '29'
union all
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `projectid.datasetid.hospital_6*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX between '10' and '29'
union all
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `projectid.datasetid.hospital_7*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX between '10' and '29'
union all
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `projectid.datasetid.hospital_8*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX between '10' and '29'
union all
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `projectid.datasetid.hospital_9*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX between '10' and '29'

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `projectid.datasetid.hospital_*` 

WHERE substring(_TABLE_SUFFIX,2,1) IN (‘1’,’2’)
```

This query specifically searches the second character, and since it only checks if that character is a 1 or a 2, it has less work to do, so the query should be much faster.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).